# PostGIS import csv encoding problem

Tags: postgis, csv

I want to import csv into PostGIS database,

I receive error massage:

```
alpha=# COPY project FROM '/home/alpha/database/project.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc1da
CONTEXT:  COPY project, line 1
```

so I find my csv's coding is `ISO-8859-1` and set `encoding = ISO_8859_1`

```
#SET client_encoding = ISO_8859_1;
```

COPY worked

but I use

```
SELECT * FROM project
```

it's give me a lot of garbled words!

so how to make it right??

Comment: This PostgreSQL question is explained on the [help page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) (look for ENCODING). It has has nothing to do with PostGIS.

Comment: @Mike I can import csv into table but it shows lots of garbled in my data,not just import problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my script, I begin with the statement:
    SET client_encoding = LATIN1;
Then
    COPY table FROM 'D:\folder\file.csv' DELIMITERS ';' CSV HEADER;

Hope this can help